# After selecting one person, selected person must dissappear from options

Tags: php, laravel, alpine.js

In the group table I select a person from the list, but after selecting one name, his name should not appear in other select options, it must show 'selected' or just disappear, so names in groups cant duplicate, 1name=1slot.

In the students list below, there must be a group's name assigned to a person if he/she is selected.
[View for a better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OCYV.png)

My groups dropdown blade:

```
<div class="row">
@for ($groupName = 1; $groupName <= $project->amount; $groupName++)
<div class="col-3">
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover text-center my-3">
<tr class="table-light">
    <th> Group #{{ $groupName }} </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    @for ($j = 0; $j < $project->studentsPerGroup; $j++)
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" style="overflow:auto; max-height:260;">
        <option selected>Assign Student</option>
        @foreach ($students as $student)
        <option value="{{ $groupName }}">{{ ucwords($student->name) }} {{ $loop->iteration . '/' . $loop->count }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @endfor
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
@endfor
</div>
```

And persons list table:

```
enter code her<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover text-center my-3">
<tr class="table-light">
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Group Name</th>
    <th width="220px">Action</th>
</tr>
    @foreach ($students as $student)
<tr class="align-middle">
    <td class="text-left">{{ ucwords($student->name) }}</td>
    <td>Group#</td>
    <td>
        <form action="{{ route('students.destroy', $student->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" title="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Please Confirm')">
                Remove
            </button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

It's a school project and I really tried hard. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you want to do this with alpinejs but not sure how to do it? If you use alpine i would recommend you do everything in alpine and don't mix php in it.

Comment: Its a bit confusing, you are trying to delete student in second part of your code? How do you store students groups on your database field, pivot table etc?

Comment: Well I have three tables, prjects-students-groups. Group needs project id and student id. Group model hasMany students, belongsTo 1 project. This view opens up when you enter project, in project I specified how many groups and slots there will be. Currently I can't find a way to send selected(option field) data from groups into DB table 'Group'.